# Rust warns of never used function, but said function is used

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

this is my `src` folder structure

```
src/
|-- main.rs
|-- problems
|   |-- mod.rs
|   |-- p1.rs
|   `-- p2.rs
`-- utilities.rs
```

I have my `utilities.rs` file containing 2 functions I use in `p1.rs` and `p2.rs`. In both `p1.rs` and `p2.rs` are the lines

```
#[path = "../utilities.rs"]
mod utilities;
```

that, as far as I understand, allow me to use the functions defined in the `utilities.rs`
The  two functions defined in `utilities.rs` are

```
pub fn get_lines(num: &str) -> Vec<String> {...}
pub fn split(s: &String, separator: &str) -> Vec<String> {...}
```

In `p2.rs` I use them both, but in `p1.rs` I only use `get_lines`. This causes cargo to warn me of a "never used" function, it being `split`, when I run or build. But the function is used, and not only in functions that are never called, so I don't understand why cargo is warning me. It would seem I have to use every single module function in every single file where I include a self-made module, because if I do call `split` in `p1.rs` then the warning disappears. What do I not understand?

To be clearer, the problem is that when I `cargo run` I get the following

```
warning: function is never used: `split`
  --> src/problems/../utilities.rs:23:8
   |
23 | pub fn split(s: &String, separator: &str) -> Vec<String> {
   |        ^^^^^
   |
   = note: `#[warn(dead_code)]` on by default
```

Comment: Add the command and output to the question.

Comment: @GrzegorzŻur You're right, done.

Answer (score 5):

You should generally **never** use the `#[path]` attribute in ordinary situations, because it lets you make this mistake.

The key to understanding Rust modules is that `mod` *defines* a module and its contents. Every `mod` item is a different module from any others. Therefore, if you write `mod` twice in such a way that both refer to the same file, *that file gets compiled twice, producing two copies of what's defined in that file.* That's why you're getting `dead_code` warnings — you've defined two different functions, `problems::p1::utilities::split()` and `problems::p2::utilities::split()`, and one of them isn't used.

As a general rule, in projects with simple structure, **there should be only one `mod` item** for any module source file in your project. In this case, the natural place to locate that `mod` item is in `main.rs`, and it should be:

```rust
mod utilities;
```

Then, you can refer to this module in your `p1.rs` or `p2.rs` as:

```rust
use crate::utilities;
```

On the other hand, maybe the `utilities` are more associated with the `problems` module only. In that case, you would

- place the file at `src/problems/utilities.rs`,
- write `mod utilities;` in `src/problems/mod.rs`, and
- refer to the utilities in `p1` and `p2` as either `use super::utilities;` (relative path) or `use crate::problems::utilities;` (absolute path).

In general, the procedure for introducing a new module is:

- Pick a module to be the parent module of your module. (Don't think in directories and files, think in modules.)
- Write `mod my_module_name;` in that parent module.
- Put the file where it needs to be, given that. (If you try to compile the program at this point, the compiler will tell you what file is missing; or if you use `rust-analyzer` in an IDE you can ask it to create the file.)
- Everywhere you want to *use* that module, refer to it by the appropriate absolute or relative path according to where its `mod` is; and use `use` if you want to make a convenient short alias for its path.

Comment: rustc should emit "BEGINNER WARNING: DO NOT USE `#[path]` UNLESS YOU REALLY KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING" every time `#[path]` is used.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Good news! Clippy will soon (in 1.62) warn against this scenario: [`duplicate_mod` lint](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/#duplicate_mod). Sadly newcomers often don't use clippy, but at least its something.

Comment: @kmdreko Yes [I was already told that in an internals thread I've opened](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/path-causes-issues-for-beginners/16714/3?u=chrefr).

Answer (score 2):

You could use a crate import instead of the path modifier (which I cannot prove, but is probably the guilty one), in both `p1` and `p2`:

```rust
use crate::utilities;
```